# Redirecting Data From One WebForm to Another

Tags: asp.net, infragistics

I'm using the Infragistics tool for ASP.NET.

I have a WebForm, `webform1`, where I placed a WebDataGrid control of infragistics. Now, I want a user to select the row and have it redirect the data to a textbox on another WebForm, `webform2`.

How can I get the selected row from `webform1` to `webform2`?

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: No need to close. There was a question in there, it was just a run-on sentence. Since edited, so hopefully it's more clear.

Answer (score 2):

You have a number of options:

1. You can reference the [PreviousPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.previouspage.aspx) property in the Page property of WebForm2. See [Cross Page Posting in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139.aspx) for more information.
2. You could do a Response.Redirect and then [URLEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx) your values and send them in the QueryString as GET values which can be referenced from the next page.
3. You can change your logic so that you encapsulate all of the functionality you require onto one Web Form, using either a [MultiView or Wizard](http://windowsdevcenter.com/pub/a/windows/2006/03/21/multiview-and-wizard-controls-in-aspnet-20.html) control.